# Upgrade version of Android

Tags: android, platform

I have Android 2.3.4 version installed on my device ( Samsung Galaxy mini GT-S5570) .
Can I upgrade the version of Android to be Android4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flash a new ROM. Check the [xdadevelopers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) forums to search for a ROM for your device. And also check [CyanogenMOD Device's page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Devices). There you will find instructions of how to flash the ROM.

**Warning**: By flashing a ROM you will be voiding your warenty. Your first option would be to check if Samsung has released an Android update for your device.

Comment: If you think it doesn't belong here, why answer it?

Comment: I also dont recommend Flashing your device, since he didnt ask for this. You should look into offcial android updates, and if your device supports it instead.

Comment: Because I am not sure. I am removing my doubt ;-).

Comment: @Doomsknight I don't think Samsung has an official update for that device. But yes, it would be the best option.

Comment: @algui91 Then it should really be specified in the answer, with warning on the flashing option - only if you know what your doing, else more harm than good may be done.